# Aggregating and group by in Pandas considering some conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have an excel file which simplified has the following structure and which I read as a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN':['US02079K3059', 'US02079K3059', 'US02079K3059', 'US02079K3059', 'US02079K3059', 'US02079K3059', 'US02079K3059', 'US02079K3059', 'US00206R1023'],
               'Name':['ALPHABET INC.CL.A DL-,001', 'Alphabet Inc Class A', 'ALPHABET INC CLASS A', 'ALPHABET A', 'ALPHABET INC CLASS A', 'ALPHABET A', 'Alphabet Inc. Class C', 'Alphabet Inc. Class A', 'AT&T Inc'], 
               'Country':['United States', 'United States', 'United States', '', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States'],
               'Category':[ '', 'big', 'big', '', 'big', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'average'],
               'Category2':['important', '', 'important', '', '', '', '', '', 'irrelevant'],
               'Value':[1000, 750, 60, 50, 160, 9, 10, 10, 1]})
```

I would love to group by ISIN and add up the values and calculate the sum like

```
df1 = df.groupby('ISIN').sum(['Value'])
```

The problem with this approach is, I dont get the other fields 'Name', 'Country', 'Category', 'Category2'.

My objective is to get as a result the following data aggregated dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN':['US02079K3059',  'US00206R1023'],
               'Name':['ALPHABET A', 'AT&T Inc'], 
               'Country':['United States', 'United States'],
               'Category':['big', 'average'],
               'Category2':['important', 'irrelevant'],
               'Value':[2049, 1]})
```

If you compare df to df1, you will recognize some criteria/conditions I applied:

- for every 'ISIN' most commonly appearing field value should be used, e.g. 'United States' in column 'Country'
- If field values are equally most common, the first appearing of the most common should be used, e.g. 'big' and 'test' in column 'Category'
- Exception: empty values don't count, e.g. Category2, even though '' is the most common value, 'important' is used as final value.

How can I achieve this goal? Anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try convert `''` to `NaN` then drop `'Value'` column then groupby 'ISIN' and calculate mode then map the values of sum of `'Value'` column grouped by 'ISIN' to 'ISIN' column so to create 'Value' column in your Final result:

Basically the idea is to converting empty string `''` to NaN so that it doesn't count in the mode and we are defining a function to handle such cases when mode of particular column groupedby 'ISIN' is `NaN` because of `dropna=True` in `mode()` method

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return x.mode().iat[0]
    except IndexError:
        return float('NaN')
```

Finally:

```
out=(df.replace('',float('NaN'))
       .drop(columns='Value')
       .groupby('ISIN',as_index=False).agg(f))
out['Value']=out['ISIN'].map(df.groupby('ISIN')['Value'].sum())
out['Value_perc']=out['Value'].div(out['Value'].sum()).round(5)
```

**OR**

Via passing `dropna=False` in `mode()` method and anonymous function:

```
out=(df.replace('',float('NaN'))
       .drop(columns='Value')
       .groupby('ISIN',as_index=False).agg(lambda x:x.mode(dropna=False).iat[0]))
out['Value']=out['ISIN'].map(df.groupby('ISIN')['Value'].sum())
out['Value_perc']=out['Value'].div(out['Value'].sum()).round(5)
```

Now If you print `out` you will get your desired output

Comment: Ty, for the simplified case it functions pretty good, but somehow I get an error if I use my original data that is read into a dataframe using a csv file. IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 Any suggestions u may have?

Comment: @Numpy that was due to NaN so updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Maaan u r a legend, as a newbie to python and pandas I don't fully understand what u did there but it works perfectly! U saved my life! Please allow me one extra question: How can I add the percentages of 'Value', so that I can get another column percentage with the values 2049/2050 = 99,951% and 1/2050 = 0,0488%. I very much appreciate your answer, again ty sooo much!

Comment: @Numpy updated answer....added explaination and extended solution...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Ty so much again!!! U r a legend. May be my last reply was misleading. Is it possible to have the percentage as float like 0.99951? Would that be possible? :)

Comment: @Numpy updated answer...kindly  have a look **:)**

Comment: I dont know how to thank you, u r a genius!!!!! That helps me a lot and works perfectly. Thank you 1,000 times!!!!

Comment: @Numpy btw I am still  a noob...Glad it helped you....happy coding **:)**